# Problems understanding intermittent inconsistencies when loading data with SSIS package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, common-table-expression

**The problem**

During the passed few months the below described procedure has worked without any problems a vast majority of the times it has run (on 2008 r2). We have, however, three instances of incorrectly connected data. The question is, what is causing this and how do I remedy it?

```
DATA_PreImp

    sourceid    col01   col02   col03   col04   col...
    100001      John    Smith   
    100002      Calvin  Klein
    100003      Peter   Parker
    100004      Moe     Greene
```

Usually the rendered result is that the attribute is connected to the Items_Main correctly but sometimes (less than 1%) the order is scrambled so that the value of col01 is not connected to the same Items_Main as the value of the rest of the columns.

Any insights as to what is causing this would be most appreciated.

**The data moving procedure**

We have an SSIS package that transfers data from a flat table called DATA_PreImp to a structure consisting of three related tables (attribute based).

- Items_Main should contains one row for each row in DATA_PreImp
- Items_Featurevalues contains one row for each column value of a row in DATA_PreImp
- Items_MainRel contains the connection between Items_Main and Items_FeatureValues

The first step in the SSIS package inserts the data from DATA_PreImp to Items_Main and inserts the generated identifier into the TARGET_ID column in the empty DATA_PreImpMappingTMP table.

```
insert into items_main(creationdate, status)
output inserted.itemid into DATA_PreImpMappingTMP(TARGET_ID)
select getdate(), '0' from data_preimp
order by sourceid asc;
```

The second step in the SSIS package fill the Items_MainRel table with TARGET_ID (Itemid originally) and an identifier for the feature (in this case a 5).

```
insert into items_mainrel(itemid, featureid)
output inserted.itemrelid into DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP(INDREL_ID)
select TARGET_ID, 5 from DATA_PreImpMappingTMP
order by TARGET_ID asc;
```

The third step is to fill the SOURCE_ID column in the DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP table with the SOURCE_ID from DATA_PreImp.

```
with cte as (select sourceid, row_number() over (order by sourceid asc) as row from data_preimp)
update m set m.SOURCE_ID = s.sourceid, m.FEAT_ID = 5
from DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP as m
join cte as s on s.row = m.ROW;
```

The last step is to fill the Items_FeatureValues table with data from DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP and DATA_PreImp.

```
insert into items_featurevalues(itemrelid, languageid, fnvarchar)
select DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP.INDREL_ID, 0, data_preimp.col01
from DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP
join data_preimp on (DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP.SOURCE_ID = data_preimp.sourceid)
where FEAT_ID = 5
```

**Data table structure**

Here is what is needed to create the scenario:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_PreImp](
    [sourceid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [col01] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col02] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col03] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col04] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col05] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col06] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col07] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col08] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col09] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [col10] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DATA_PreImp] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [sourceid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_PreImpMappingTMP](
    [ROW] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TARGET_ID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ROW] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items_Main](
    [Itemid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [creationDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [purchdate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [logindate] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_Main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Itemid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DATA_PreImpMapping2TMP](
    [ROW] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SOURCE_ID] [int] NULL,
    [INDREL_ID] [int] NULL,
    [FEAT_ID] [int] NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ROW] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items_Features](
    [featureId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [featureRef] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [featureName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [creationDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [status] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fieldType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [featureType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [featureDesc] [varchar](500) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_Features] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [featureId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items_MainRel](
    [ItemRelId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Itemid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [featureId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_MainRel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ItemRelId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Items_FeatureValues](
    [valueId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ItemRelId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [languageId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FnVarChar] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [FInt] [int] NULL,
    [FImage] [int] NULL,
    [FNText] [ntext] NULL,
    [FSmallDateTime] [smalldatetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Items_FeatureValues] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [valueId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO    

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_MainRel]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_MainRel_Items_Features] FOREIGN KEY([featureId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items_Features] ([featureId])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_MainRel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_MainRel_Items_Features]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_MainRel]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_MainRel_Items_Main] FOREIGN KEY([Itemid])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items_Main] ([Itemid])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_MainRel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_MainRel_Items_Main]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_FeatureValues]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_FeatureValues_Items_MainRel] FOREIGN KEY([ItemRelId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Items_MainRel] ([ItemRelId])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Items_FeatureValues] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Items_FeatureValues_Items_MainRel]
GO


INSERT INTO DATA_PreImp (col01,col02,col03,col04) 
VALUES('John', 'Smith', '1964', 'NewYork'),
        ('Calvin', 'Klein', '1960', 'Washington D. C.'),
        ('Peter', 'Parker', '1974', 'Losangles'),
        ('Moe', 'Greene', '1928', 'Lasvegas')


INSERT INTO Items_Features (featureRef, featureName, creationDate, [status], fieldType, featureType, featureDesc)
VALUES ('firstname','First_Name', GETDATE(), 0, 'FnVarChar', 3, 'FirstName'),
    ('lastname','Last_Name', GETDATE(), 0, 'FnVarChar', 3, 'LastName'),
    ('Birth','Birth', GETDATE(), 0, 'FnVarChar', 3, 'Birth'),
    ('City','City', GETDATE(), 0, 'FnVarChar', 3, 'City')
```

Comment: I get foreign key violation on the second script. There is no record in dbo.Items_Features with featureID = 5 (as hard-coded into that script). Should that be a different featureID used in the script or is there a record missing from dbo.Items_Features?

Comment: Are you using transactions in your inserts?  Does error handling in the SSIS package throw any useful data?  Are there other processes running on the same db/tables at the same time that could be causing concurrency issues?

Comment: with something this complex, without the actual package and all the inner workings, it is going to be quite challenging to locate the problem.  We need way more information....

Comment: Is the source data correct?

Comment: How SSIS finds and put into the script 5 as in `where FEAT_ID = 5` and everywhere else? It look to me that the problem is in finding corrct ID at some point, am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the computed column CUST_CD. After a lot of researching, it seems that the BULK INSERT does not like complex computed types (see [Using SQL Server spatial types in SSIS data load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4031909/using-sql-server-spatial-types-in-ssis-data-load)). The solution is to removed the computed column and just make it a varchar(20) NULL. Then I created a new Execute SQL Task that updates any NULL rows with the computed value.